# How fork() works with command ls

Tags: fork

I have a code for using fork and execute a command, the command is date
This code works 
Im wonder how to do it with the command ls | more

```
   case 0 :
            *// Send the command from child proccess*
            dup2(pipefd[1], fileno(stdout));
            close (pipefd[0]);
            execl ("/bin/date","date",0,NULL);
   default:
            dup2(pipefd[0], fileno(stdin));
            close (pipefd[1]);
            **// HERE ,,, im wonder hot to get more result**
            cin.getline(str, 1023);
            cout << "The date is " << str << endl;
            died= wait(&status);
```

Comment: You'll need `fork()`/`execl()` twice - once for `ls` and once for `more`. And you'll need to provide the pipe between the two and set it up properly.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same, but i dont know how to code it. Looking an example like that.